# Typescript lodash no default export for one function

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I am trying to import only one function from lodash like this:

```
import get from 'lodash/get';
```

I already installed lodash and @types/lodash, and I'm getting this error:

> @types/lodash/get/index"' has no default export.)

Comment: You can try my answer but this should work if the ts file it you are using is this one; https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/354cec620daccfa0ad167ba046651fb5fef69e8a/types/lodash-es/get/index.d.ts

Comment: try using `import {get} from 'lodash'`. It imports only one function but requests the whole file. This would be useful if you use bundler like webpack 2, which uses **tree shaking** and bundles only the required functions.

Comment: You need to set "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, in your tsconfig.json

Comment: @DanHomola it works

Comment: In my case I was in watch mode and all I had to do was restart webpack.

Answer (score 21):

You can import a single function from lodash using `import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';` in typescript with the `esModuleInterop` flag in the compiler options (tsconfig.json)

example

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the most correct answer. I will add that you might still see an error in red in VSCode to the effect: [ts] Module '"/build/brower/gitrepos/whatever/src/web-apps/angular/node_modules/@types/lodash/uniqBy"' has no default export. But the project should build and everything should be ok.

Answer (score 10):

i had same problem, and i ended up here,

so here is the solution:

you need to install **lodash-es**

```
npm install --save lodash-es
```

instead of normal *lodash*

and read this link

https://medium.com/@armno/til-importing-lodash-into-angular-the-better-way-aacbeaa40473

**update 1:
it should really be easier, but anyway**

*point 1*: install typings

```
 npm i -D @types/lodash-es
```

*point 2*: import from "lodash-es" not "lodash"

*point 3*: import like this, it's proper way (otherwise you will get a much larger bundle)

```
import  orderBy  from 'lodash-es/orderBy';
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I had to do to make it working for `lodash.random`, which I think should reasonably work for `lodash.get` too :

- Install the function of lodash you want with `npm install --save lodash.random`
- Install the types linked to it: `npm install --save-dev @types/lodash.random`
- Set `compilerOptions.allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to `true` in your `tsconfig.json`
- Import it like `import { random } from 'lodash';`

Answer (score 2):

Only way I could solve this was like:

`import get = require("lodash.get");`

See a similar example here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14160

The other suggestion, `import * as get from 'lodash.get';` fails like this if you don't have the proper configuration:
TS2497: This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag and referencing its default export

And actually, I have this in my tsconfig.json:

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```

And it fails anyway (not for *React* ,*moment* and other packages, but only for this lodash.get package). So, the ugly `require` do the trick (I mean ugly just because it breaks the ES6 import syntax, meaning we miss the code consistency).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working for a similar error by using:

```
import * as get from 'lodash.get';
```

Comment: For me, it says: TS2497: This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag and referencing its default export.

Answer (score -3):

You can either use:

```
import { get } from "lodash";
```

Or:

```
import { get } from "lodash-es";
```

For the latter you will need to install the appropriate typing file (which apparently includes the `default` export):

```
npm install @types/lodash-es --save-dev
```

Comment: No, it won't work. Only if `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` is set in tsconfig

Comment: Fixed the second example, sorry.