# This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag and referencing its default export

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai

I'm creating my API test framework with TypeScript and I'm new to it.

I created this helper file `assertions.ts`

```
import * as chai from 'chai';

interface response {
    status: number
    body: object
}

const assertResponseStatusCode =
    (response:response, statusCode:number) =>
        chai.expect(response.status).to.deep.equals(statusCode);

const assertSuccessResponseStatusCode = (response:response) =>
    assertResponseStatusCode(response, 201)

export = {assertSuccessResponseStatusCode}
```

Then I started using them on my spec file as bellow

```
import * as auth from '../Helpers/auth';
import * as assert from '../Helpers/assertions';
import { user } from '../Samples/user';

describe('login', () => {
    it('should return access token with valid credentials', async() => {
        const response = await auth.login(user);
        console.log(response.body);
        assert.assertSuccessResponseStatusCode(response);
    });
});
```

I'm getting this error **This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag and referencing its default export.**. for this line `import * as assert from '../Helpers/assertions';` although `esModuleInterop` is set as true in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: for me I has to turn on both `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, "esModuleInterop": true,`. reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55579495/6908282

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just ran into this too and the other answer gives one solution but I think the better solution in this case is to change:

```
export = {assertSuccessResponseStatusCode}
```

To:

```
export {assertSuccessResponseStatusCode}
```

The first method is TypeScript's interop with CommonJS modules, but you can only import those like `import assertions from './assertions'`. The second is an ESM export and can imported as either `import { assertSuccessResponseStatusCode } from './assertions'` *or* `import * as assertions from './assertions'`. It also allows you to have default exports along with the other exports.

Answer (score 7):

It is fixed for me when I changed the import statement to `import assert from '../Helpers/assertions';`

actually, what was causing the problem is the equal sign in the export where I export one object `export = {assertSuccessResponseStatusCode}`

If changed into `export{assertSuccessResponseStatusCode}`, import all will work then.